# Does anyone know if the ibm jdk associated with websphere 8.5.5.19 supports debugging via jpda using dt_socket option on windows 10?

Tags: windows, debugging, intellij-idea, websphere, jpda

Intellij automatically generates read-only debug options that include dt_socket but we are using this ancient jvm that "may" only support dt_shmem on windows.  Just want to know for sure that it will never work with the version of intellij we are using.

rtfm says https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sdk-java-technology/8?topic=applications-debugging-java

Secondary followup question.  Is it possible to run websphere 8.5.5.19 on the oracle or openjdk jvm in a non-production environment.

Answer (score 0):

dt_socket works on Windows as well. The documentation is a bit misleading in that dt_shmem is only an option on Windows.

For the record, that probably isn't an *ancient* JVM in there unless it just hasn't been updated. If you updated the JDK when you updated WAS to 8.5.5.19, it would have a version of Eclipse OpenJ9 from about a year ago (and Eclipse OpenJ9 is single source across all JDK releases, so it includes all the same JVM goodies as in recent JDK releases).